# Setting up a reverse SSH tunnel to access remote ubuntu pc from windows

Tags: 20.04, ssh, remote-access

My work desktop is an Ubuntu, and I'm trying to access it from home through a Windows laptop.
Something like TeamViewer doesn't work, since these kinds of remote access options are blocked by the firewall. My organization is using Zscaler VPN software to allow remote access, but unfortunately that seems to be incompatible with Linux. And I know that reverse tunnel should be possible from giving someone else access in the past.

But how to do this if there is a Windows pc on one side? Most tutorials online seem to assume both sides run Linux. Just command line access such as through PuTTY would already be helpful, but some kind of remote desktop would be preferred.

Comment: If you want to install SSH server to your Windows PC, consider https://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: Zscaler's website claims that they do have a Linux client. Ask your organization to enable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, there was no need to set up such a construction.

with Zscaler turned on, plain SSH clients allow remote access (forward tunnel),once I've found the IP of the target computer